# Hyperledger Fabric : failed to send proposal to peers

Tags: java, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am facing a big problem while using hyperledger Fabric 1.2 . I used java SDK 1.1 and while compiling the app, I got an error (shown below) and peers status is down . I tried to restart the docker container in order to change the peers status but it doesn't solve the problem. Does any one have an idea about how to solve this problem .. and thank you

```
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.do>CreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
            at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
            at com.digitalberry.bcncore.CoreApp.main(CoreApp.java:71)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)

        >2018-08-13 12:50:08.157 DEBUG 980 --- [  restartedMain] io.opencensus.trace.Tracing              : Couldn't load full implementation for TraceComponent, now trying to load lite implementation.

        >java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.opencensus.impl.trace.TraceComponentImpl
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
            at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
            at io.opencensus.trace.Tracing.loadTraceComponent(Tracing.java:86)
            at io.opencensus.trace.Tracing.<clinit>(Tracing.java:33)
            at io.grpc.internal.AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.getEffectiveInterceptors(AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.java:423)
            at io.grpc.internal.AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.build(AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.java:398)
            at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.EndorserClient.<init>(EndorserClient.java:47)
            at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Peer.sendProposalAsync(Peer.java:194)
            at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.sendProposalToPeers(Channel.java:2357)
            at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.getConfigBlock(Channel.java:741)
            at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.parseConfigBlock(Channel.java:1150)
            at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.initialize(Channel.java:948)
            at com.digitalberry.bcncore.repository.FabricRepository.init(FabricRepository.java:186)
            at com.digitalberry.bcncore.repository.FabricRepository$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e7c8296e.invoke(<generated>)
            at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738)
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
            at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
            at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85)
            at com.digitalberry.bcncore.aop.logging.LoggingAspect.logAround(LoggingAspect.java:85)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:629)
            at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:618)
            at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
            at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:62)
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
            at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
            at com.digitalberry.bcncore.repository.FabricRepository$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f48c7dd5.init(<generated>)
            at com.digitalberry.bcncore.web.rest.DocumentResource.<init>(DocumentResource.java:54)
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
            at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:122)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:271)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
            at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
            at com.digitalberry.bcncore.CoreApp.main(CoreApp.java:71)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)

        >2018-08-13 12:50:08.158 DEBUG 980 --- [  restartedMain] io.opencensus.trace.Tracing              : Couldn't load lite implementation for TraceComponent, now using default implementation for TraceComponent.

        >java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.opencensus.impllite.trace.TraceComponentImplLite
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
            at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
            at io.opencensus.trace.Tracing.loadTraceComponent(Tracing.java:98)
            at io.opencensus.trace.Tracing.<clinit>(Tracing.java:33)
            at io.grpc.internal.AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.getEffectiveInterceptors(AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.java:423)
            at io.grpc.internal.AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.build(AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.java:398)
            at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.EndorserClient.<init>(EndorserClient.java:47)
            at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Peer.sendProposalAsync(Peer.java:194)
            at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.sendProposalToPeers(Channel.java:2357)
            at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.getConfigBlock(Channel.java:741)
            at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.parseConfigBlock(Channel.java:1150)
            at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.initialize(Channel.java:948)
            at com.digitalberry.bcncore.repository.FabricRepository.init(FabricRepository.java:186)
            at com.digitalberry.bcncore.repository.FabricRepository$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e7c8296e.invoke(<generated>)
            at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738)
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
            at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
            at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85)
            at com.digitalberry.bcncore.aop.logging.LoggingAspect.logAround(LoggingAspect.java:85)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:629)
            at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:618)
            at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
            at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:62)
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
            at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
            at com.digitalberry.bcncore.repository.FabricRepository$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f48c7dd5.init(<generated>)
            at com.digitalberry.bcncore.web.rest.DocumentResource.<init>(DocumentResource.java:54)
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
            at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:122)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:271)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
            at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
            at com.digitalberry.bcncore.CoreApp.main(CoreApp.java:71)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)

        >2018-08-13 12:50:08.276 ERROR 980 --- [  restartedMain] org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel       : Sending proposal to peer1.org1.digitalberry-infra failed because of: gRPC failure=Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=Unable to resolve host peer0.org1.digitalberry-infra, cause=java.net.UnknownHostException: peer0.org1.digitalberry-infra
            at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
            at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(Unknown Source)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(Unknown Source)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(Unknown Source)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
            at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver$JdkResolver.resolve(DnsNameResolver.java:335)
            at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver$1.run(DnsNameResolver.java:173)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
        }

        >java.lang.Exception: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: Unable to resolve host peer0.org1.digitalberry-infra
            at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.sendProposalToPeers(Channel.java:2405)
            at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.getConfigBlock(Channel.java:741)
            at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.parseConfigBlock(Channel.java:1150)
            at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.initialize(Channel.java:948)
            at com.digitalberry.bcncore.repository.FabricRepository.init(FabricRepository.java:186)
            at com.digitalberry.bcncore.repository.FabricRepository$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e7c8296e.invoke(<generated>)
            at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738)
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
            at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
            at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85)
            at com.digitalberry.bcncore.aop.logging.LoggingAspect.logAround(LoggingAspect.java:85)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:629)
            at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:618)
            at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
            at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:62)
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
            at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
            at com.digitalberry.bcncore.repository.FabricRepository$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f48c7dd5.init(<generated>)
            at com.digitalberry.bcncore.web.rest.DocumentResource.<init>(DocumentResource.java:54)
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
            at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:122)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:271)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
            at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
            at com.digitalberry.bcncore.CoreApp.main(CoreApp.java:71)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
        Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: Unable to resolve host peer0.org1.digitalberry-infra
            at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:526)
            at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$UnaryStreamToFuture.onClose(ClientCalls.java:467)
            at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:37)
            at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23)
            at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40)
            at io.grpc.internal.CensusStatsModule$StatsClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusStatsModule.java:684)
            at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:37)
            at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23)
            at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40)
            at io.grpc.internal.CensusTracingModule$TracingClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusTracingModule.java:391)
            at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:471)
            at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$300(ClientCallImpl.java:63)
            at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.close(ClientCallImpl.java:553)
            at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.access$600(ClientCallImpl.java:474)
            at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:591)
            at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
            at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
        Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: peer0.org1.digitalberry-infra
            at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
            at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(Unknown Source)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(Unknown Source)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(Unknown Source)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
            at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver$JdkResolver.resolve(DnsNameResolver.java:335)
            at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver$1.run(DnsNameResolver.java:173)
            ... 3 common frames omitted

>2018-08-13 12:50:08.301 ERROR 980 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
```

my application property config is like bellow :

```
application:
    basedir: @project.basedir@
    fabric: 
        peerUserPath : ${application.basedir}/target/classes/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.digitalberry-infra/users/Admin@org1.digitalberry-infra/msp
        peerCAPath : ${application.basedir}/target/classes/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.digitalberry-infra/users/Admin@org1.digitalberry-infra/tls
        ordererCAPath : ${application.basedir}/target/classes/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/digitalberry-infra/users/Admin@digitalberry-infra/tls
        sampleStoreFilePath : ${application.basedir}/HFCSampletest.properties
        peer0Name: peer0.org1.digitalberry-infra
        peer0Address: grpcs://peer0.org1.digitalberry-infra:7051
        peer1Name: peer1.org1.digitalberry-infra
        peer1Address: grpcs://peer1.org1.digitalberry-infra:8051
        eventHub0Address: grpcs://peer0.org1.digitalberry-infra:7053
        eventHub1Address: grpcs://peer1.org1.digitalberry-infra:8053
        ordererName: orderer.digitalberry-infra
        ordererAddress: grpcs://orderer.digitalberry-infra:7050
        channelName: mychannel


 */
```

Answer (score 0):

you have given peerAddress as

```
peer0Address: grpcs://peer0.org1.digitalberry-infra:7051
```

where **peer0.org1.digitalberry-infra** does not exist on internet so you should change it to localhost everywhere

```
peer0Address: grpcs://localhost:7051
```

And then the grpcs won't work on localhost due to unavailable certificates so change to **grpc**

```
peer0Address: grpc://localhost:7051
```

Try making this changes in peerAdress everywhere.